# Method changing parameter value of a string (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, a-star

Last week I've started working on an artificial intelligence online course from EdX and I've been trying to advance on the project, but I haven't been able to fix a specific bug I've encountered. The project consists on building an A* agent that finds all 4 corners on a Pacman maze.

The course forum is not very active at the moment, and I didn't find something similar on Stackoverflow, so I decided to ask myself. The code I'm working on is part of a bigger project build by the course and the class that solves the maze problem is CornersProblem that has a constructor, a getStartState, isCorner, isGoalState, getCostOfActions, cornersHeuristic and getSuccessors methods.

The piece of code that throws the bug is the following:

```
    def getSuccessors(self, state):
    """
    Returns successor states, the actions they require, and a cost of 1.
     As noted in search.py:
        For a given state, this should return a list of triples, (successor,
        action, stepCost), where 'successor' is a successor to the current
        state, 'action' is the action required to get there, and 'stepCost'
        is the incremental cost of expanding to that successor
    """
    successors = []
    self._expanded += 1  # DO NOT CHANGE
    for direction in [Directions.NORTH, Directions.SOUTH, Directions.EAST, Directions.WEST]:
        x, y = state[0]
        **print direction
        dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(direction)**
        nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
        if not self.walls[nextx][nexty]:
            nextState = (nextx, nexty)
            cost = self.getCostOfActions(direction)
            if self.isCorner(self, nextState):
                state[1] += 1
            successors.append(((nextState, state[1]), direction, cost))
    return successors
```

This method calls directionToVector:

```
    def directionToVector(direction, speed = 1.0):
    print direction
    dx, dy =  Actions._directions[direction]
    return (dx * speed, dy * speed)
directionToVector = staticmethod(directionToVector)
```

And I'm getting a KeyError message: 'N' saying that 'N' is not in the dictionary and it should be 'North'. If I print the direction before I pass it to directionToVector method it outputs 'North', but after it's inside the method the output is 'N'. Here's the error message:

[Command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfgHy.png)

I'm not very experienced with Python, so probably there is something that I'm missing here. This is my first question on this forum, so thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: If youa re getting an error, post the full error message and the stack trace. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: could you print `direction` which i assume is 'N' and `Actions._directions` dictionary and add it in question please.

Comment: I've added what I think you asked for. Tell me if you need anything else.